# Javascript- Compare 2 object excluding certain keys

Tags: javascript, jestjs, equality

I'm creating 2 objects based on given values in my jest test and expect that they would be equal except of the property `uuid` which is generated indevidualy for each object.

`uuid` can be deeply nested multiple times. for example:

```
const object1 = { uuid: '5435443', name: 'xxx', branches: [{ uuid: '643643', children: [{ uuid: '65654' /* and so on */ }] }];
const object2 = { uuid: '7657657', name: 'xxx', branches: [{ uuid: '443444', children: [{ uuid: '09809' }] }];
```

How can I compare the objects, ignoring `uuid` property?

Comment: You can omit keys with [`_.omit`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit) and deep compare objects with [`_.isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove uuid first than compare them.

```
const object1 = { uuid: '5435443', name: 'xxx', branches: [{ uuid: '643643', children: [{ uuid: '65654' /* and so on */ }] }]};
const object2 = { uuid: '7657657', name: 'xxx', branches: [{ uuid: '443444', children: [{ uuid: '09809' }] }]};

const removeUuid = o => {
  if (o) {
    switch (typeof o) {
    case "object":
      delete o.uuid;
      Object.keys(o).forEach(k => removeUuid(o[k]));
      break;
    case "array":
      o.forEach(a => removeUuid(a));
    }
  }
}

removeUuid(object1);
removeUuid(object2);

expect(object1).toBe(object2);
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! What did I not think of this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [expect.any](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectanyconstructor) to ignore `uuid` attribute. Just make sure that the attributes are existing, and the uuid is a string:

```
describe("Compare 2 objects", () => {
  it("should ...", () => {
    const actual = { uuid: '5435443', name: 'xxx', branches: [{ uuid: '643643', children: [{ uuid: '65654' }] }] };

    const expected = {
      uuid: expect.any(String), // <--
      name: 'xxx',
      branches: [{ uuid: expect.any(String), children: [{ uuid: expect.any(String) }] }]
    };

    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded to achieve this with the following solution:

```js
const object1 = { uuid: '5435443', name: 'xxx', branches: [{ uuid: '643643', children: [{ uuid: '65654' /* and so on */ }] }] };
const object2 = { uuid: '7657657', name: 'xxx', branches: [{ uuid: '443444', children: [{ uuid: '09809' }] }] };

const compareExcludeKeys = (object1, object2, excludeKeys = []) => {
  if (Object.keys(object1).length !== Object.keys(object2).length) return false;
  return Object.entries(object1).reduce((isEqual, [key, value]) => {
    const isValueEqual = typeof value === 'object' && value !== null
      ? compareExcludeKeys(value, object2[key], excludeKeys) 
      : excludeKeys.includes(key) || object2[key] === value;
    return isEqual && isValueEqual;
  }, true);
};

console.log(compareExcludeKeys(object1, object2, ['uuid']));
```