# I want to compare two json objects excluding one of the keys from it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have two objects x,y and i want to compare both of these excluding one of the keys "c"

```
let x = {a: 5, b: 6, c: "string"}
let y = {a: 5, b: 8, c: "string"}
```

How i am trying to compare it is -

```
JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(y)
```

Above works but it will compare all keys I want to exclude c in comparison here. What's the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Here in output i want to have a comparison of just x = {a:5, b:6} and y = {a:5, b:8}

Comment: Do you know which are the props that you require to compare? Or, you only know the props that you need to ignore from comparison?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript- Compare 2 object excluding certain keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68890700/javascript-compare-2-object-excluding-certain-keys)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks the answer is almost close to what i wanted. isEqual and omit did the work for me.

Comment: @Sofiyarao I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for quick responses on my question but below was an easy method from which I could implement the above logic

```
import omit from "lodash/omit";
import isEqual from "lodash/isEqual";

let x = {a: 5, b: 6, c: "string"},
y = {a: 5, b: 8, c: "string"}

result = isEqual(omit(x, ['c']), omit(y, ['c']))
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code obtains all the keys from object `x`, removes `c` from the list, and then performs the comparison.

```
let x = { a: 5, b: 6, c: "string" };
let y = { a: 5, b: 6, c: "another string" };

console.log(
  Object.keys(x)
    .filter((key) => key !== "c")
    .every((key) => x[key] === y[key])
);
```

Answer (score 1):

array.sort requires a `comparator` function. You can use the exact same thing here

```
function myObjComparator (x, y) {
  if (x.a != y.a) return y.a - x.a;
  return y.b - x.b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I would NOT stringify objects in order to compare them.
The reason is quite simple and is that you MUST to be sure that the order of the members are the same, otherwise the result won't be correct.

Ex:

```
// objects are equals
const y = { a: '1', b: '2' }
const x = { b: '2', b: '1' }
// but result is not what you expect
JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(y) // false
```

But, if you can ensure that the order of the members is always the same, stringify is fast and a good option.

You can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in order to avoid the "c" property

```
const remappedX = { ...x, c: undefined };
const remappedY = { ...y, c: undefined };
JSON.stringify(remappedX) === JSON.stringify(remappedY); // true
```

Or alternatively

```
const allowedKeys = Object.keys(x).filter((k) => k !== 'c');
JSON.stringify(x, allowedKeys) === JSON.stringify(y, allowedKeys);
```

More generic method is to loop over Object key or alternatively to entries

```
for(const key of Object.keys(x)) {
   if (key === 'c') {
      continue;
   }
   if (x[key] !== y[key]) {
         return false;
   }
}
return true;
```

But, if your object is nested, you need to use a deep equality algorithm, which is of course slower.

More generic answer has been given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144249/16881741)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
JSON.stringify(x, ['a','b']) === JSON.stringify(y, ['a','b']);
```

better solution:

```
function replacer(key, value) {
  // Filtering out properties
  if (key === 'c') {
    return undefined;
  }
  return value;
}
JSON.stringify(x, replacer) === JSON.stringify(y, replacer);
```

correct better solution:

```
const filterKeys = (obj) => Object.keys(y).filter(k => k !== 'c').sort()
JSON.stringify(x, filterKeys(x)) === JSON.stringify(y, filterKeys(y));
```

Comment: A side benefit of this solution is that it fixes the case where `a` and `b` are defined in reverse order in x or y

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```js
const x = {a: 5, b: 8, c: "string1", d: {e: 9}}
const y = {a: 5, b: 8, c: "string2", d: {e: 9}}

const compare = (obj1, obj2, except = []) => {
    
    if (Object.keys(obj1).length < Object.keys(obj2).length) {
        [obj1, obj2] = [obj2, obj1];
    }
    
    for (const obj1Key in obj1) {
        if (except.includes(obj1Key)) continue;

        if (!obj2.hasOwnProperty(obj1Key)) return false;

        if (typeof obj1[obj1Key] === 'object') {
            if (typeof obj2[obj1Key] !== 'object') return false;
            
            const isEqual = compare(obj1[obj1Key], obj2[obj1Key]);
            
            if (isEqual) continue
            
            return false;
        }

        if (obj1[obj1Key] !== obj2[obj1Key]) return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}

console.log(compare(x, y, ['c']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ternary operator to compare both the objects.

**Demo :**

```js
let x = {a: 5, b: 6, c: "string"};
let y = {a: 5, b: 8, c: "string"};

function compare(obj1, obj2) {
  return (obj1.a != obj2.a) ? false : (obj1.b != obj2.b) ? false : true;
}

console.log(compare(x, y));
```

By deleting the unwanted properties and then compare using `JSON.stringify()`

**Demo :**

```js
let x = {a: 5, b: 6, c: "string"};
let y = {a: 5, b: 8, c: "string"};

delete x.c;
delete y.c;

console.log(JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(y));
```

Comment: This would work but in the case where there is a change in order of the json.. Stringify would miss that case and just compare two strings. I have answered this question, but thanks I will be able to use this logic in some other usecase